# What is the meaning of "of" in "be of interest"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "be of interest" in the following sentence,

> The lecture will be of interest to history students.

?

Does "The lecture will be **of interest** to history students" mean
"The lecture **of interest** will be to history students" ?

What is the meaning of "of" in the sentence?

Does "of" in "be of interest" mean "of" in "a leaf of tree" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that history students will be interested in the lecture.

The "of" in "be of interest" is part of an idiomatic expression.  Please review the following post in ell.stackexchange.com describing [the Meaning and usage of “be of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47382/meaning-and-usage-of-be-of)

Comment: Interestingly enough, my dictionary (NOAD) has definitions for both "be of" and "of interest".

Comment: I'm not surprised.  I think dictionaries like the NOAD embrace colloquialisms more and more rapidly (hence the "New" in NOAD). Yesterday's colloquialism is tomorrows accepted grammar.