# Can we generalize the structure of "be + of (+ adjective) + noun (+ to)" to every noun?

Tags: phrase-usage

Based on these:

[what-is-the-meaning-of-of-in-be-of-interest](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162098/what-is-the-meaning-of-of-in-be-of-interest)

[what-can-i-be-of-help](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12720/what-can-i-be-of-help)

[what-is-the-meaning-of-of-interest-to-anyone-in-the-following-sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278775/what-is-the-meaning-of-of-interest-to-anyone-in-the-following-sentences)

[what-is-the-difference-between-interest-and-of-interest-or-between-abstrac](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/237541/what-is-the-difference-between-interest-and-of-interest-or-between-abstrac)

[Whats-the-meaning-of-be-of-Be-of-help-Be-of-importance-Be-of-use](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-meaning-of-be-of-Be-of-help-Be-of-importance-Be-of-use)

I can say the following sentences are correct (please correct me if I am wrong):

> 1. The interests of the child **are of paramount importance**.
> 2. This **is of great importance** to society.
> 3. This book **is of interest to** children.
> 4. This strategy **is of benefit** for company.
> 5. He **was of assistance to** me in researches for my books.
> 6. He **is of great help to** the poor.
> 7. This tool **is of use to** repair a car.

The question:

Can I generalize the structure of "be + of  (+ adjective) + noun (+ to)" to every other noun as well or this structure is idiomatic and only goes with some special nouns?

For example are these sentences correct:

> 8. He **is of regard to** me.
> 9. People who litter **are of no respect**.
> 10. This book **is of boredom to** me.
> 11. Your whispers **are of distraction to** me.
> 12. Your acts **are of fear to** me.

A complementary question:

Is this structure colloquial and common in speech? It seems to me that this structure is more of a literary structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sentences 8 - 12 are not correct. You could say *Your whispers are* **a** *distraction to me,* otherwise you need to completely re-word them.

Yes, the structure is fairly formal. In everyday conversation we would usually say that something *is important* rather than *is of importance*.

Answer (score 1):

No, this construction is only used with a limited selection of abstract nouns, mostly to do with how we think about or evaluate things.

You gave the example *importance* and *interest*. Others are *concern*, *relevance*, *significance*.

But none of your later examples work.